# numpy array printing wrong random numbers

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

i dont understand why when i print the list of matrices, it prints out these random values! any insight would be great! thanks

```
matList = np.empty([2,2,2], dtype = int)


a = np.array([[1, 0],
          [3, 3]])
b = np.array([[1, 1],
          [3, 3]])

np.append(matList,a)
np.append(matList,b)
print (a)
print (b)
print (matList)
```

this is the output im getting

```
[[1 0]
 [3 3]]
[[1 1]
 [3 3]]
[[[6029427 4259908]
 [3866700 3801155]]

[[5242972 7274610]
 [7471207 7143521]]]
```

Comment: basic problem is that you did not read the docs for append.

Comment: ready the docs for `empty` as well.

Comment: ok i read it and im guessing its because it appends them to a copy, not the actual array. so what can i do instead?

Comment: Also do you want to keep those random values of the original 'empty' array?  You are working with arrays not python lists.

Answer (score 2):

`empty` returns an array of the specified size, but filled 'random' values, what ever happened to be in those memory slots:

```
In [936]: mat = np.empty([2,2,2], dtype=int)
In [937]: mat
Out[937]: 
array([[[          0, -1231162112],
        [-1222623584,   139401936]],

       [[  139401936,   139401936],
        [-1230408992, -1222184576]]])
In [938]: a = np.array([[1, 0],
     ...:           [3, 3]])
     ...: b = np.array([[1, 1],
     ...:           [3, 3]])
     ...:
```

`np.append` not only returns a new array, but without `axis` flattens both inputs - the result is a 1d array:

```
In [939]: np.append(mat,a)
Out[939]: 
array([          0, -1231162112, -1222623584,   139401936,   139401936,
         139401936, -1230408992, -1222184576,           1,           0,
                 3,           3])
```

What exactly are you trying to produce?

With a list append (and initial 'empty' list)  (`np.empty` array does not mean the same thing):

```
In [941]: alist = []
In [942]: alist.append(a)
In [943]: alist.append(b)
In [944]: alist
Out[944]: 
[array([[1, 0],
        [3, 3]]), array([[1, 1],
        [3, 3]])]
In [945]: np.array(alist)
Out[945]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 1],
        [3, 3]]])
```

The result is a (2,2,2) array, same as `np.array([a,b])`

You could also produce this by setting elements of `mat` with `a` and `b` (I would normally say `by inserting`, but I don't want to confuse you with `np.insert`):

```
In [951]: mat = np.empty((2,2,2), int)
In [952]: mat[0,:,:]=a
In [953]: mat[1,:,:]=b
In [954]: mat
Out[954]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [3, 3]],

       [[1, 1],
        [3, 3]]])
```

This changes the values of `mat` in-place.